# clear margin between normal div and fixed div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, laravel

i have to divs 
one is fixed and its the header for all pages 
and the ather is the content 
and this is my code

```
<style>
#print-head {
    display: none;
}
@media print {

    #print-head {
        display: block;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0pt;
        left:0pt;
        right: 0pt;
        text-align: center;
    }
}
</style>
<div id='print-head'>
    page header herer for all page
</div>
<div id='content'>
    content here coming from foreach loop
</div>
```

my problem the div content gat many many lines thats print preview in the first page everything is ok 
the header with content looking like this 
[image]

but in the next page the content will be stack with header like this 
[image]

i need a code to make content div always get margin from top not just in the first page 
how can i clear:both margin between first div and the second div in every page thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
    #print-head {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left:0px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px 0;
}
```

Comment: like that the head div gone from print preview